# IE rendering mode

Tags: internet-explorer

I am a bit confused on how IE 9 and IE 10 decide to render

On one of my customers machine it was using IE 7 document mode and on another it was using standard mode.

Does the doctype affect how it renders?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The mode could be controlled by the [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meta tag or HTTP response header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

or if you want to render with the latest available mode you could use `edge`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: So what happens if I have doctype of:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

and no X-UA-Compatible tag? It seems to behave differently based on the machine I use. I also don't want to change to DOCTYPE because it break in other browsers. (This is a legacy app)